# How to fix: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am a totally new to swift. I am trying to set up a screen with 3 textfields so the user can enter data. I used the code line: `nameField.delegate = self` , but I always get an error message: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`. Could anybody help me fixing that problem? :)

I have already tried to force unwrap the value, but that did not work.

```
private func configureTextFields(){
       nameField.delegate = self
       amountField.delegate = self
       dateField.delegate = self
   }
```

I also set up an extension at the bottom. Maybe I did a mistake there:

```
extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

.

Comment: Remove Private from your FUNCTIOn,  and then try again. Hope it works

Comment: Set up a breakpoint. Then check what's `nil`'.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you aren't calling the `configureTextFields` function you wrote until `viewDidLoad` if you are calling it from the initializer, your outlets are not yet set up and will be `nil`. You probably want your code to look something like this:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     configureTextFields()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you connected your `nameField` from `StoryBoard` to your `IBOutlet` by control-dragging from the StoryBoard to the the variable?

[image]

Check [Connect UI to the Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html) from Apple.